# @URL.Action on button click to load partial view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

In my form I have email field , search Button and place holder for the partial view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{   
    Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.emailAddress, new { style = "width:400px" , @class = "emailValue"})
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.emailAddress) 

<button name="button" value="search" id="SearchResultbtn">
                    Search</button>
 <div id="searchResult">
                </div>

}
```

The search result is displayed in partial view by using jquery

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $("#SearchResultbtn").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#searchResult").load('@Url.Action("AdminSearchResult", "Administration")');
    });
});
```

In my controller I have a main Action method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateAdmin(string button, Administration admin)
{
}
```

and Action method that handles partial view

```
public ActionResult AdminSearchResult(string sortOrder, int? page)
{
    var result = Administration.GetAdministrationList();
    return PartialView("AdminSearchResult", result);
}
```

Now what I want is to first validate email on button click if email is valid then load the partial view if not throw the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You again, @user2225604! You don't need any script or anything fancy at all to do this. You already have unobtrusive js enabled as per my previous answer, so...

From the behaviour you mentioned, I'm thinking you simply need something like this:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AdminSearchResult", "ControllerName", null, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "searchResult", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }))
```

instead of:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
```

Then you can get rid of the script entirely. You might have to pass a routeValue for that sortOrder parameter in your Ajax.BeginForm, but other than that, you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks Moby. I learned an another way to load partial view dynamically but that does not help with validation. the modalState is not validated before loading

Comment: Do you have the unobtrusive validation script included in the page as well as jquery validation? Post your <head> tag. Also, check out Brad Wilson's famed tutorial on it here: http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-validation.html make sure you have the we.config key he mentions: <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>

Comment: Yes, I checked the blog and I am almost doing the same using data annotation. Well i have decided to take a break and take a look later.Sometime you just need a break.